# Trouble with a First Order Differential Equation Using Substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}-20+x^2y^2=0$, using the substitution $y=u^{-1}\frac{du}{dx}$, and $y(1)=1$

So I first started by differentiating y, $$y'=-u^{-2}\frac{du}{dx}+u^{-1}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$, and I substituted this back into he equation and get

$$(-u^{-2}\frac{du}{dx}+u^{-1}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2})x^2-20+x^2u^{-2}(\frac{du}{dx})^2=0$$ and simplifyng a bit I get

$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-u^{-1}\frac{du}{dx}+u^{-1}(\frac{du}{dx})^2-\frac{20u}{x^2}=0$$, and then I have trouble working with this, substituting $u=e^{mx}$ dos't work out when I do it because of the squared differential.  Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: I don't see the mistake honestly, I wrote it a bit clearer but still don't see my error

Comment: this equation is an example of riccati equation. the substitution gives you a linear second order equation for $u$. in this case it looks like a variant of the airy equation.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot chain rule in $y'=-u^{-2} (\frac{du}{dx})^2+u^{-1}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$.

That will reduce the first derivative term.

Comment: So then I get $u^{-1}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-\frac{20}{x^2}=0$, would this be correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.